# Very complex database architecture, how to deal with it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have worked on several rails applications and now I work on a very complex one, from the database side. A lots of nested models, several polymorphyc associations...

How you deal with that complexity ? How can I know that we are working in the good direction ? What about performance issues ?

Thansk for your opinions.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful.  Could you provide examples of some of the things you have in mind?  Are the object-relational capabilities of Postgresql being used, or is it merely being because it's free? etc.

Comment: Many data type, many data, many files, many domain names, many routes.. in the same app. No very special feature of postgresql use there, only beacause it's free and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to estimate the performance of the queries that your application runs against the database. Then you can try to optimize the queries, for example, by adding some indexes. Maybe in some cases you will also need to consider denormalizing some data to get better performance.

Performance of the queries may also depend on your data size. If you have really big data set and queries are optimal, then you may consider introducing (distributed) caching. Or if data model allows that think of partitioning your database on several nodes to improve query performance.

But still the first step should be a setup of some SQL query performance monitoring.

Answer (score -3):

You should consider a NOSQL solution such as MongoDB or CouchDB.  Sometimes an RDBMS is not the right tool for the job.

http://www.mongodb.org/

http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: Why that ? I feel it will be much harder to code.

Comment: If you have lots of polymorphism, you may end up with way more tables. MongoDB let's you store and search JSON objects.  In that case, you don't need to have the same "columns" in each "row" and you can easily embed objects (just as you do in JSON).  On top of that, there are libraries that make it easy, for example Mongoid and mongomapper.